# SCDF S3 Source app (version 3.0.1) com.amazonaws.SdkClientException

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

**(SCDF 2.7.1 & Skipper 2.6.1)**
Deployment -> Local Kubernetes Instance

**(Starter App)**
Applications version 3.0.1
kafka docker

Created a stream S3 Source -> Log, on deploy the 'S3 Source' app throws below exception. But the stream gets deployed and works as expected. Any info on how to get rid of the exception.

> com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Failed to connect to service endpoint:
> at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2ResourceFetcher.doReadResource(EC2ResourceFetcher.java:100) ~[aws-java->sdk-core-1.11.792.jar:na]
> at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2ResourceFetcher.doReadResource(EC2ResourceFetcher.java:70) ~[aws-java->sdk-core-1.11.792.jar:na]
> at >com.amazonaws.internal.InstanceMetadataServiceResourceFetcher.readResource(InstanceMetadataServiceResour>ceFetcher.java:75) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.792.jar:na]
> at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2ResourceFetcher.readResource(EC2ResourceFetcher.java:66) ~[aws-java-sdk->core-1.11.792.jar:na]
> at com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils.getItems(EC2MetadataUtils.java:402) ~[aws-java-sdk-core->1.11.792.jar:na]
> at com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils.getData(EC2MetadataUtils.java:371) ~[aws-java-sdk-core->1.11.792.jar:na]
> at >org.springframework.cloud.aws.context.support.env.AwsCloudEnvironmentCheckUtils.isRunningOnCloudEnvironm>ent(AwsCloudEnvironmentCheckUtils.java:38) ~[spring-cloud-aws-context-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
> at >org.springframework.cloud.aws.context.annotation.OnAwsCloudEnvironmentCondition.matches(OnAwsCloudEnviro>nmentCondition.java:38) ~[spring-cloud-aws-context-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) >~[spring-context-5.2.13.RELEASE.jar:5.2.13.RELEASE]
> at >org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader$TrackedConditionEvaluator.>shouldSkip(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:477) ~[spring-context->5.2.13.RELEASE.jar:5.2.13.RELEASE]
> at >org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConf>igurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:131) ~[spring-context->5.2.13.RELEASE.jar:5.2.13.RELEASE]
> at >org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(Config>urationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:120) ~[spring-context-5.2.13.RELEASE.jar:5.2.13.RELEASE]
> at >org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(Conf>igurationClassPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.2.13.RELEASE.jar:5.2.13.RELEASE]
> at >org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry>(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:236) ~[spring-context-5.2.13.RELEASE.jar:5.2.13.RELEASE]
> at >org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostPr>ocessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:280) ~[spring-context-5.2.13.RELEASE.jar:5.2.13.RELEASE]
> at >org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(Po>stProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:96) ~[spring-context-5.2.13.RELEASE.jar:5.2.13.RELEASE]
> at >org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractA>pplicationContext.java:707) ~[spring-context-5.2.13.RELEASE.jar:5.2.13.RELEASE]
> at >org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:5>33) ~[spring-context-5.2.13.RELEASE.jar:5.2.13.RELEASE]
> at >org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServer>ApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.9.RELEASE.jar:2.3.9.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot->2.3.9.RELEASE.jar:2.3.9.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot->2.3.9.RELEASE.jar:2.3.9.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:405) ~[spring->boot-2.3.9.RELEASE.jar:2.3.9.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot->2.3.9.RELEASE.jar:2.3.9.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot->2.3.9.RELEASE.jar:2.3.9.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot->2.3.9.RELEASE.jar:2.3.9.RELEASE]
> at >org.springframework.cloud.stream.app.s3.source.kafka.S3SourceKafkaApplication.main(S3SourceKafkaApplicat>ion.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
> Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
> at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a known issue, but I'm not sure how to fix it, since it occurs in the amazon SDK. I recommend you submit an issue [in github](https://github.com/spring-cloud/stream-applications/issues) so we can track it.